# Accessing tokens and response data

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, local-storage, angular2-services

Trying to figure out some basic authentication with Angular 2.  I want my component to check for a token and if it exists navigate to the proper location, but if it doesn't display the error message returned by the service. Here is the the service call:

```
this._loginService.login(loginQuery)
        .subscribe(
            (token: any) => this._router.navigate( ['User', { username: user }] ),
            (data) => { this.errorMessage = data.ErrorMessage; }
        )
```

Here is the code for the service:

```
return this._http.post('serivcelink,
                            body,
                            {headers:headers})
        .map((res : any) => {
            let data = res.json();
            this.token = data.TeamMember.UserName;
            localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
        });
```

I get the token behavior I want except that I don't get access to the response object in the component, and as such can't display the error message.

How do can I check for the token and get access to the response data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if statement to check if your token exists, else display an error message:

```
this._loginService.login(loginQuery)
        .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                    this._router.navigate( ['User', { username: user }] )
                } else {
                    this.errorMessage = data.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. I wasn't sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something within the `map` callback, i.e. `this.token` in your case:

```
return this._http.post('serivcelink,
                        body,
                        {headers:headers})
    .map((res : any) => {
        let data = res.json();
        this.token = data.TeamMember.UserName;
        localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
        return this.token; // <-------
    });
```

What you return will be receive as parameter into the callback of the `subscribe` method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This allows me to return the response but then breaks the behavior I want from my `subscribe`.  A follow up question would then be what is the best way to check for the token in the `subscribe` method before changing the route?